# Error when creating a test for a Shiny module

Tags: r, unit-testing, shiny, shinyapps, shinymodules

I want to write a unit test for a shiny module using testthat package. I am following the instruction of [mastering Shiny book](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-testing.html). It has written in this book that first we should create a test file using `usethis::use_test()` in the R console.

But when I run this code, I get this error:

> Error: Path 'my R file path' does not appear to be inside a project or package.

I appreciate any help everybody can provide.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it needs to have one "RProj" file in the output of `list.files()`

Comment: @BertilBaron . My R files weren't in an R project, so I created an R project for them, and now I have an RProj file in the output of `list.files()`. But now, when I run `usethis::use_test()` I get this error: `Error: Open file must be in the 'R' directory of the active package.
* Actual path: 'app.R'`